# How does threshold work for LinearSVC transform?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using LinearSVC as a preprocessing step for my decision tree classifier. I run LinearSVC
and then I do transform(X). I notice that the number of features reduces from around 35 to 9. I would like to know which features were actually chosen.

I know that by default transform(X) works with threshold='mean'. Can someone tell me an example of how it determines whether to keep the feature or not?

This is a my coef_.

`array([[ -2.45022173e-01,  -8.61032928e-02,  -2.39513401e-03,
         -2.07443644e-02,   2.49547244e-03,  -3.14133367e-02,
          7.09627000e-03,   3.94563929e-03,   6.78145800e-02,
          1.59497586e-01,  -1.24063075e-01,  -4.79223418e-02,
         -3.70412138e-02,   4.39187481e-02,   1.30004636e-02,
         -2.31911643e-03,  -1.63937709e-03,  -2.18402321e-03,
         -2.65601394e-03,   1.48259224e-02,  -6.15157373e-02,
         -3.65242492e-04,   8.10479000e-02,  -1.58338535e-01,
          5.06225924e-03,   1.16183358e-03,   6.44170055e-02,
         -2.56651350e-03,   1.62029008e-01,  -1.69785296e+00,
         -1.91045465e+00,  -1.64206237e+00,  -1.80735175e+00,
         -1.39504546e+00,  -1.66709852e+00],
       [  4.14083584e-01,   2.03703885e-01,   4.82783739e-03,
          7.90756359e-02,  -1.45063508e-03,   1.05486236e-01,
         -3.01145160e-01,  -7.81145855e-03,  -3.39445309e-01,
         -5.66603101e-01,   2.41489561e-01,   3.11615301e-01,
         -3.59607168e-01,  -4.04092005e-01,  -3.18262477e-03,
          8.14224001e-04,   8.64216590e-04,   6.59107091e-03,
          5.48336293e-03,  -1.76329713e-02,   2.33854833e-01,
         -1.00455178e-01,  -5.00175471e-02,   4.81448974e-02,
          3.13891484e-01,   3.54014313e-03,   3.32840843e-01,
          6.85018177e-05,  -6.75410702e-01,  -1.03258781e-01,
          2.59870671e-01,  -3.03956500e-01,  -1.58732859e-01,
         -3.89772985e-01,  -2.55624888e-01],
       [  1.06132321e-01,   1.23617156e-01,   1.40819416e-03,
          1.06118853e-01,   5.11221833e-04,  -1.68780545e-01,
          9.27425326e-02,   3.52220207e-03,   2.12134293e-01,
          3.54667378e-01,   1.22840976e-01,  -4.21232679e-01,
          3.55037449e-01,  -2.06715803e-01,   6.18856581e-02,
         -4.63662372e-03,  -5.04710160e-04,  -4.65594740e-04,
          1.01529235e-02,   1.15598254e-03,   4.49951214e-02,
          2.20830485e-01,  -1.01269555e-01,   3.03514605e-01,
         -1.27056578e-01,  -2.17123757e-02,  -2.51044202e-01,
          7.19562937e-03,  -6.74304600e-01,   2.47410746e-01,
         -7.76792375e-02,   2.26260621e-01,   3.83972532e-01,
          4.35143804e-01,   3.50074110e-02],
       [  6.33038442e-02,   3.71367520e-01,  -1.21238483e-02,
         -5.92230089e-02,  -2.69617795e-03,   2.44885573e-01,
         -1.12043386e-01,  -1.05526224e-01,  -9.88583026e-02,
         -6.09121814e-01,  -5.16313417e-01,   2.83500385e-01,
          2.04390765e-01,   9.13454922e-01,   2.12522482e-02,
          4.67960378e-03,   3.78514732e-03,  -1.89184862e-03,
         -2.35710741e-02,   2.77863999e-02,   5.93172013e-01,
         -3.98200956e-01,   2.04199614e-01,  -6.20399607e-02,
          1.19732985e-01,   1.16674647e-01,  -1.27517918e-03,
         -4.23253804e-03,  -1.82480535e+00,   9.29959444e-01,
          1.21162165e+00,   1.09899835e+00,   7.42987354e-01,
          9.61956169e-01,   8.72089435e-01],
       [  2.98336593e-01,   1.36166556e-01,   8.55303000e-04,
          1.13137553e-01,  -4.11417197e-03,   2.59650136e-01,
          7.87008264e-02,   7.22415689e-03,  -3.64334467e-02,
         -2.57473176e-02,  -1.01132206e-01,  -4.52864069e-02,
          8.62911851e-03,  -1.01396648e-01,  -1.71810251e-01,
          2.87556170e-02,  -5.75335168e-03,  -1.31809609e-03,
          2.27847222e-02,  -1.64198532e-02,  -8.11859436e-03,
         -2.60700154e-02,   1.74207263e-01,   1.10324971e-01,
          6.65055594e-02,   4.11639440e-03,  -9.68050856e-02,
          4.32464307e-02,   1.26432150e+00,   2.80210335e-02,
          1.30525549e-01,   4.34196521e-01,  -2.46460632e-01,
          3.85467301e-01,  -2.58179093e-02]])`

I have read the documentation. What I am unsure of is how this 'mean' is calculated. Is it the mean of the feature means? If I have 5 classes and 35 features, the coefficient for that feature for each class will be different. Am I supposed to find the mean of the features then find the mean of those?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting would you care to explain why so? I have read the documentation and I sincerely could not find any resource that explains the process of how it works

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.transform):

The threshold value to use for feature selection. **Features whose importance is greater or equal are kept while the others are discarded.** If “median” (resp. “mean”), then the threshold value is the median (resp. the mean) of the feature importances. A scaling factor (e.g., “1.25*mean”) may also be used. If None and if available, the object attribute threshold is used. Otherwise, “mean” is used by default.

Importance is here given by the coefficients.

Comment: @Andrew Mueller, I have read the documentation. What I am unsure of is how this 'mean' is calculated. Is it the mean of the feature means? 

If I have 5 classes and 35 features, the coefficient for that feature for each class will be different. Am I supposed to find the mean of the features then find the mean of those?

Comment: The mean of the absolute sum over the classes of the coefficients. Source [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/from_model.py#L52) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/from_model.py#L88)

Comment: I agree that is not well documented. Fix here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3829

Comment: Thanks, I actually think that this should be some attribute in the transform() function so that users who want to obtain the indices of the features selected can do so easily.

Comment: Hum.... what do you mean by attribute in the transform method? Given the information you can do ``indices = np.where(np.sum(np.abs(clf.coef_), axis=1) > thresh)[0]`` and don't need the transform method at all.

Comment: Yes, I mean perhaps expose some method to the user so they can get this easily.